# If statement inside cypress.io test

Tags: unit-testing, testing, cypress, e2e-testing

I'm new to testing and to cypress.io in particular, and I'm trying to test the registering flow in my app.

I want to check two scenarios -

1. If the user is trying to register with an existing username, an error message should be popping up
2. Else if proper inputs are inserted, the username is successfully registered

How can I do so in one test? Is there an option to use if statement with cypress?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You should split it into two cases, see https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing.html#Definition

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
   If(Cypress.$(‘error msg locator’).length > 0) {
    //error msg displayed.Do something 
}
else {
    //success login.Do something 
}
```